# Why do my items change order when I update input value in REACT?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have simple shopping cart app made with REACT and REDUX.

I have some items that are displayed on screen with input filed where number of items is changed and based on that new price i calculated. But one thing is problematic.

Price is calculated correctly when I update number of items or when I add new but but when I update number that item is rendered last. So if I update number of first item it will just end as last item on the list

```
1
2
3
4
```

Let's say that I update item `1` then list will look like this

```
2
3
4
1
```

and this is really frustrating me. This is how I display items

```js
{this.props.cart.map(item => {
  return (
    <div key={item.product.id}>
      <Item item={item}/>
    </div>
  )
})}
```

I also tried with `...reverse().map` but it does the same except it puts it on the top of page instead of bottom. I want them to stay where they are when they are updated

This is parent component of single item component. Both of them are class components, I also have this in parent component

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    cart: state.cart.cart
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Cart);
```

Thank you for your time. If you need any other info just reach out and I will provide it.

**UPDATE 1**

This is how I update cart

```js
handleChange = e => {
    if(e.target.value <= 0) {
      alert("Quantity must be grater than 0");
      return;
    }

    if(e.target.value > this.props.item.product.amount) {
      alert("Max number of products reached");
      return;
    }

    if(this.state.quantity !== e.target.value) {
      this.setState({
        quantity: e.target.value,
        // btnVisible: true
      }, () => this.props.updateCartQuantity(this.props.item.product.id, this.state.quantity))
    }
  };
```

```html
<input type="number" className="form-control" onChange={(e) => {this.handleChange(e)}} value={this.state.quantity}/>
```

This update is happening in child component

**UPDATE 2**

`updateCartQuantity` is a function

```js
export const updateCartQuantity = (productId, quantity) => {
  return {
    type: 'UPDATE_CART_QUANTITY',
    payload: {
      productId,
      quantity: quantity
    }
  }
};
```

it's data is handled here

```js
case 'UPDATE_CART_QUANTITY':
      let item = cart.find(item => item.product.id === action.payload.productId);
      let newCart = cart.filter(item => item.product.id !== action.payload.productId);

      item.quantity = action.payload.quantity;

      newCart.push(item);

      return {
        ...state,
        cart: newCart
      };
```

problem is probably in this `case` but I just can't see it

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example - use e.g. StackBlitz or SO snippets

Comment: Since I am writing this from my phone it is pretty much impossible to do it now. It was hard enough to write this post. I hope someone can provide any info on this without working example rn.

Comment: Can you show how you're updating the cart?

Comment: @Jayce444 I updated the question

Comment: What is `updateCartQuantity`?

Comment: I updated the question. It is **UPDATE 2** @Ry-

Comment: Because you remove the item then push it on the end. Why would it be anything different?

Comment: I do realize that. But what can I do about it. I am still new to React and have this problem which I want to solve really bad.

Comment: Did you consider using Array.prototyoe.map in your reducer? `cart.map(c=>c.id===action.payload.priductId?{...c, quantity: action.payload.quantity}:c)`

Comment: I did use it. But for every change it just appends that element to the end. So when I have 3 elements and update first element twice I will have 5 elements. It will copy first elements 2 times. Either I am not using it correctly or it is just not working.

Comment: **EDIT** I also realise that with cart.map edited ones stay in place. New ones are just added at the end. Hmm.. interesting. I noticed this just now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. It is fixed thanks to @HMR comment on post. I just realised what I was doing.

Instead of `cart.filter` I should use this

```js
let newCart = cart.map(c => c.id === action.payload.productId ? {...c, quantity: action.payload.quantity} : c);
```

and remove

```js
newCart.push(item);
```

.map will take care of looping through elements so there is no need of pushing element to `newCart.push(item)`

Thank you for your comment. Hope this helps someone :)